# How to check if all required fields are filled to enable submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate multiple required fields. This code currently works for at least one required field is filled out, but I don't know how to make it work so that it works for all required fields. Could someone help me? I should mention that this includes checkboxes and radios as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[required]').on('keyup', function(){
            var empty = false, val = '';
            val = $(this).val();
            if (val.length) {
                empty = false;
            } else {
                empty = true;
            }
            if (empty) {
                $('#register').css('opacity', '0.2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#register').css('opacity', '1').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: you should listen to form submit instead of keyup for every input.

Comment: radio inputs are designed to have at least one of them check, so you should make one of the radio inputs check by default. with that you do not have to validate the radio inputs.

Comment: I'm using webflow so I already have disabling on the form submit, this is mostly for the visual aspect of it. But still I need help checking dynamically for every single required field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work like this, i guess.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[required]').on('keyup', function() {
            var empty = false;
            $('input[required]').each(function(){
                var val = $(this).val().trim();
                if(val.length == 0 || typeof val == 'undefined'){
                    empty = true;
                }           
            })
            if (empty) {
                $('#register').css('opacity', '0.2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#register').css('opacity', '1').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It's working. But its not working with checkboxes/radios. How can I make it check for that?

Comment: Hi, glad to hear that. Yeah radio buttons is a little different. In webflow you have a group name for your radio buttons in the settings. You can use it to check the value like: value 
= $('input[name=yourGroupName]:checked', '#yourFormId').val()

Comment: To check if theres a radio chosen, just check, if its undefined like in my example above. Checkboxes can be validated like: if($(this).is(':checked')){...   If you have further trouble, let me know ;)

Comment: Thank you again. I think I'm fine for the radios, I just set a default one to be selected on page load.

For the checkboxes, how can I make sure at least 2 checkboxes are selected within a group? I'm not sure how to edit the code above. I have this code: if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length >= 2) { ... but I'm not sure how to input it inside the other if statement.

Comment: You do the opposite. Check if its less than 2. after the first if statement you make a second one: if($('input:checkbox:checked').length < 2){ empty = true...